# date in generate id is not up to date

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have write this code to generate unique id, based on date. the problem is the date was not up to date. I want the id like this

```
2013081901 - if user input data on 19/08/2013 
2013082002 - if user input data on 20/08/2013
```

the problem is, i got id like this

```
2013081901 - user input data on 19/08/2013 
2013081902 - user input data on 20/08/2013
```

this is my code :

```
 Dim cnnOLEDB As New OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)

    sql = "SELECT MAX(sampleID) FROM Spec_1"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cnnOLEDB)
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While dr.Read()
        Try
            If Not IsDBNull(dr(0)) Then
                txtSampleID.Text = (dr(0) + 1).ToString
                'txtSampleID.Text = dr(0).ToString
            Else

                txtSampleID.Text = Format(Date.Today, "yyMMdd") + "01"


            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtSampleID.Text = "0"

        End Try
    End While
```

Comment: Use SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx] as you know you get only one row with one column in the resultset in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just consider:

- What happens if, in one day, you have more than 99 entries? For example,

  ```
  2013081901 - input data 19/08/2013 
  2013081902 - input data 19/08/2013 
  2013081903 - input data 19/08/2013 
  [...]
  2013081998 - input data 19/08/2013 
  2013081999 - input data 19/08/2013 
  20130819?? - input data 19/08/2013
  ```
- What happens with the 100th day entry?

  ```
  2013081901 - input data 19/08/2013 
  2013082002 - input data 20/08/2013 
  2013082103 - input data 21/08/2013 
  [...]
  2013112598 - input data 25/11/2013 
  2013112699 - input data 26/11/2013 
  20131127?? - input data 27/11/2013
  ```
- If you'll only receive one entry per day, there's no need for the complimentary two digits:

  ```
  20130819 - input data 19/08/2013 
  20130820 - input data 20/08/2013
  ```

Maybe a different kind of ID algorithm would be advisable.

In any case, the specific problem you asked lies within this line:

```
    txtSampleID.Text = (dr(0) + 1).ToString
```

You're simply increasing the value, without changing the date-bound part.
You may extract the increment part by using a Mod operator, and adding the correct date, like this:

```
    txtSampleID.Text = Format(Date.Today, "yyMMdd") + ((dr(0) + 1) Mod 100).ToString
```

Comment: i have use all the methods but still face the same problem, is there any solution to generate id based on year+month+date+(increment number)